# PHP: Adding time to current time?

Tags: php, time

I am trying to add 15minutes to the current time. I am using the following code:

```
$curtime = date('H:i');                     
$newtime = $curtime + strtotime('+15 minutes');
```

But this still only prints the current time and not the current time + 15.

I want it to add 15mins like so

e.g. If the time is 12:30 the time after addition will be 12:45

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Close, you want:

```
$new_time = date('H:i', strtotime('+15 minutes'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
echo date('H:i', (time() + (15 * 60)));
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$curtime = date('H:i');
$newtime = strtotime($curtime) + (15 * 60);
echo date('H:i', $newtime);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this - `strtotime("+15 minutes")`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to make it work in Object-oriented way, here is the solution:

```
$currentTime = new DateTime();
$currentTime->add(new TimeInterval('PT15M'));
// print the time
echo $currentTime->format('H:i');
```

Requires PHP >= 5.3

Comment: what do you mean? Object-oriented PHP is the trend.

Comment: well first its not because you know OOP that you are better, second this solution is not as efficient as the best answer since probably yours calls strtotime in the object. so you are over building something super simple.