# Dynamic end date for countdown

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently trying to sort out a system on my website (with limited coding experience) that doesnt have many references out there, it would seem.

I currently have paypal IPN integration (untested), that i then use to update the database to give the user "time" on their account. i also have a "stop/start" function in their account that allows them to stop and start their time, with the idea being when they "start" their time will start to count down. conversely, whilst they are "stopped", their countdown will not count down. i guess its similar to pausing an active subscription, but mine is over a short term period.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET 
            `user_id`=$user_id, 
            `timeadded`=$timeadded,             
            `amountpaid`=$mc_gross, 
            `token`=$txnId, 
            `currtime`=TIMESTAMP()");
```

^ that is the snippet i am using to update the mysql table.

```
$new_time = date('H:i', strtotime('+$timeadded'));
```

this is what im currently working [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161138/php-adding-time-to-current-time) to allow me to calculate an end date WITHOUT the start/stop feature i mentioned above. im unsure as to how to proceed from here to integrate that feature though, as obviously the end date would need to be dynamically changing based around other variables than the currentdate.

Ive also referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617999/time-elapsed-with-pause-logic-mysql-timediff-and-php) which i think might lead me along the correct track but ive been unsuccessful as of yet.

```
//time when start clicked
$first  = new DateTime
//time when stop clicked
$second = new DateTime

//when start is clicked
exec(mysql_query("UPDATE `newtable` SET `userid`=$userid, `start`= $first"));
//when stop is clicked
exec(mysql_query("UPDATE `newtable` SET `userid`=$userid, `end`= $second"));

//use array to select all entries from newtable where userid=$userid (can fill this in if wanted).

$elapsed = $first->diff( $second );
$timeleft = (strtotime($timeadded) - strtotime($elapsed)); 
$updateelapsed = mysql_query("UPDATE `newtable` SET `userid`=$userid, `elapsed`=$elapsed")

$allelapsed = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newtable WHERE userid=$user_id");
$allelapsedarray = mysql_fetch_array($allelapsed);
$timeelapsed = array_sum($allelapsedarray);

//so now i have my total time spent "started", i should be able to compare that to the amount of time they bought. if its more than that, they are rejected, otherwise can continue as normal.
```

so thats what i have thus far for the start/stop feature to be included. this was just done on the fly after coming across the second link i gave above, and i feel its a more fruitful way of going forward than the potential method i mentioned in the first few paragraphs.

to the below comment - it wont update my database with regards to the start/stop time, nor the elapsed time column. given those things it wont bar people from accessing those areas that need "time", but i assume that that will fix itself when the above is sorted. this method ive developed also seems long winded so i might be overlooking a far simpler way of coding this semmingly straightforward task. thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: You have so much text... What's not working?

Comment: What exactly is the stop/start used for?

Comment: to start/stop the users ability to display things on the site.